# iOS Object Capture Implementation: How do I follow the API and setup?

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui, ios17

I was following the WWDC23 tutorial for implementing Object Capture into my app and I just seem to get more and more confused as I try to follow it. I'm decently capable of using Swift for the more basic UI design components and 2D functions, but I seem to struggle with the implementation of the Apple API's when it comes to things like the new object capture. The code below that I have is simply the WWDC23 code which I do not understand how to utilize. My errors can be seen below. How should I split the code up, what classes should I make, and how do I go about implementing the API? My app is simply trying to use the object capture to create USDZ files of real life objects and save them for use in my app.

```
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI

var session = ObjectCaptureSession() // ObjectCaptureSession not in scope
var configuration = ObjectCaptureSession.Configuration()
configuration.checkpointDirectory = getDocumentsDir().appendingPathComponent("Snapshots/")

//getDocumentsDir() does not exist

session.start(imagesDirectory: getDocumentsDir().appendingPathComponent("Images/"),
configuration: configuration)

struct CapturePrimaryView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ObjectCaptureView(session: session)
        }
        ZStack {
                ObjectCaptureView(session: session)
                if case .ready = session.state {
                    CreateButton(label: "Continue") {
                        session.startDetecting()
                    }
                }
            }
        ZStack {
                ObjectCaptureView(session: session)
            }
        ZStack {
                ObjectCaptureView(session: session)
                if case .ready = session.state {
                    CreateButton(label: "Continue") {
                        session.startDetecting()
                    }
                } else if case .detecting = session.state {
                    CreateButton(label: "Start Capture") {
                        session.startCapturing()
                    }
                }
            }
        ZStack {
                ObjectCaptureView(session: session)
            }
        if session.userCompletedScanPass {
                VStack {
                }
            } else {
                ZStack {
                    ObjectCaptureView(session: session)
                }
            }
        if session.userCompletedScanPass {
               VStack {
                   CreateButton(label: "Finish") {
                       session.finish()
                   }
               }
          } else {
               ZStack {
                   ObjectCaptureView(session: session)
               }
           }
        ReconstructionProgressView() // Cannot be found in scope
                .task {
                    var configuration = PhotogrammetrySession.Configuration()
                    configuration.checkpointDirectory = getDocumentsDir()
                        .appendingPathComponent("Snapshots/")
                    let session = try PhotogrammetrySession(
                        input: getDocumentsDir().appendingPathComponent("Images/"),
                        configuration: configuration)
                    try session.process(requests: [
                        .modelFile(url: getDocumentsDir().appendingPathComponent("model.usdz"))
                    ])
                    for try await output in session.outputs {
                        switch output {
                            case .processingComplete:
                                handleComplete()
                                // Handle other Output messages here.
                        }}}
    }

}
```

Comment: Please spend some time formatting code in your question, and be sure you are supplying a valid [mcve].

Comment: Copy things one by one and deal with one error at a time. Read every line until you know what each line is doing.